# Differentiate dialogs depending on an event

Tags: jquery, function, dialog

This is my first question asked here and I am also new to programming. I am building a GUI using Jquery. I have a form submission page and I can't figure out how to assign different functions to different buttons. For example: I have a SUBMIT button, and a HOME button. I want a seperate dialog for each when it's pressed and another seperate dialog for when you refresh or leave the page. Is this possible with Jquery? I hope I made myself understandable! Thank you!

Nicole

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do this. You will need to bind events like mouse click and key pressed events, and on the handlers you show different message boxes. You can use same message box, you just have to change the content of the div container before displaying message box. Comment if you require some sample code.

**Update:**

For example, in html you will add *onclick* on button click, like this

```
<input id="btnSave" type="submit" value="Save" 
    onsubmit="javaScript:btnSaveClick();" onclick="javaScript:btnSaveClick();" />
```

And in javascript you will have

```
function btnSaveClick() {
   $("#divDialog").dialog("open");
}
```

assuming you have

```
<div id="divDialog" title="Save clicked">
    Your message goes here.
</div>
```

In similar way you can do for other buttons too. Just make sure all the **Id** your assigning are unique.

Go to [jQuery](http://jquery.com) site and read documentation, that will help you learn fast.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but some sample code would be appreciated! Total noob :)

Comment: Gr8. Glad it helped you. Mark your question answered. [Faqs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)